# Parse nested JSON column to SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to parse nested JSON column in one of my sql table. Nested column has a key value "text" in various places. I want all the values of this key "text" concatenated next to each other in a single cell.

Below is my sample data.

```json
`{       "version": 1,       "type": "doc",       "content": [         {           "type": "paragraph",           "content": [             {               "type": "text",               "text": "ABC - 1234"             },             {               "type": "hardBreak"             },             {               "type": "text",               "text": "EFG - 648"             }           ]         },         {           "type": "paragraph",           "content": [             {               "type": "text",               "text": "Above EFG is a reissue of 4 payments, that status is at Issued/Requested. "             },             {               "type": "hardBreak"             },             {               "type": "text",               "text": "This payment has not been issued & an payfac file has not been produced. "             },             {               "type": "hardBreak"             },             {               "type": "text",               "text": "Please can you:"             }           ]         },         {           "type": "bulletList",           "content": [             {               "type": "listItem",               "content": [                 {                   "type": "paragraph",                   "content": [                     {                       "type": "text",                       "text": "explain what the status \"Issue/Requesed\" means"                     }                   ]                 }               ]             },             {               "type": "listItem",               "content": [                 {                   "type": "paragraph",                   "content": [                     {                       "type": "text",                       "text": "explain how this status occured"                     }                   ]                 }               ]             },             {               "type": "listItem",               "content": [                 {                   "type": "paragraph",                   "content": [                     {                       "type": "text",                       "text": "would there be any reconcilation issues if I was to change the status to \"Paid/None\" on 1-Jan?"                     }                   ]                 }               ]             }           ]         },         {           "type": "paragraph",           "content": [             {               "type": "text",               "text": "Thank you."             }           ]         }       ]     }`
```

Tried the below code

```
SELECT ID, [Key], Texts
FROM TEST_Table
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Description)
WITH 
(    
    Texts varchar(max) '$.content.content.text' 
) as TextJson;
```

But got nothing. Need help please.

Comment: Your example json isn't valid so i'm not surprised you can't query it. At least you should try to provide a json string which one could use to test your code. But content is an array, so content.content will not succeed in getting the text, you need something like content[0] etc

Comment: It's not valid JSON I'm afraid. Among other things JSON uses `"` to wrap string literals and property names, not `'`, plus your example seems to be missing an opening `{` and finishes with an extra `]`.

Comment: thats the JSON string I got from Python URL response.

Comment: Looks better now, what's the expected result you want for the above json?

Comment: We can see number of keys "text". I want all the values from this "text" key concatenated as a paragraph. I want to do this in SQL.

Comment: What's the expected result? This JSON document contains *multiple* `text` elements. Do you want one row per `text` ? Or somehow combine all of them in one string?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos somehow combine all the text key's value in one string as a paragraph

Comment: There are no paragraphs in SQL or even text. There are newline or tab characters. Post an example of what you actually want. And why - the current form is probably *easier* to use in a client application. With SQL Server, you could probably use a recursive CTE to extract all `text` values and then use `STRING_AGG` to concatenate them using newlines as a separator. That's not very pretty.

Comment: If you care about paragraphs, you should keep in mind that extracting the `text` values will lose the layout defined by the `paragraph` and `hardBreak` elements

Comment: I am sorry. I just want all the Text key's value in one cell ( in a row) Please ignore the paragraph

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want this but here's one solution:

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "version": 1,
    "type": "doc",
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Please assign ticket to RCA team."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "RCA Team"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tClient code \u2013 5374 \u12345 Apple Financial"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tDividend Task ID \u2013 12345"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tPrevious MI IR Number - 12345"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Against the above task please can I have the following data:"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tHURN"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tPartyURN"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tEligible Share Balance"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tCash Currency Dividend Due"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tTax Deducted"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tholder name including any joint holders"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tCurrent full address"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tShare balance against task"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}';

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  cast(-1 AS bigint) AS parentKey, cast([key] AS bigint) AS [currentKey], value, 1 AS level
    FROM    OPENJSON(@json, '$.content') o
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  c.currentKey, cast(o.[key] AS bigint), o.value, c.level + 1
    FROM    cte c
    CROSS apply openjson(c.value, '$.content') o
)
SELECT  string_agg(json_value(value, '$.text'), ' ') within GROUP (ORDER BY [level], parentKey, currentkey)
FROM    cte
WHERE   JSON_VALUE(value, '$.type') = 'text'
```

I use recursive CTE to call every subjson part and then aggregate it together into one long string, ordered by parentkey and currentkey.

I used ' ' as paragraph splitter, but you can use whatever you want if you have some specific needs

Comment: My data is actually from a SQL table SELECT ID, Description FOM TABLE_A. Can you please help on how I can now pass the Description from this table to this code?

Comment: replace `openjson(@json` with `TABLE_A cross apply openjson(description`

Comment: I tried but sorry unable to code it correctly. Can you please help me with correct code which will be a life saver and big learning

Comment: Here you go: https://dbfiddle.uk/szhnnfRr

Comment: It worked like a cham. Absolutely fantastic and my heartful thanks to you..

Comment: You probably need to change the order by in the string_agg to something appropriate. This is why it's important to display the *expected result* when asking questions or have much better specification

Comment: I have edited the JSON code in the question for your reference. Kindly have a check on this and help me for aggregating in the same order please

Comment: You still haven't provided the expected result. "same order" doesn't say much. you can try this fiddle i guess: https://dbfiddle.uk/xf4YjRqU, it sorts by "breadth"

Comment: Absolutely this is what I needed. Apologies for not being able to express properly. Thanks again

Comment: cast(concat(REPLICATE('0', 10), '_', right('0000000000' + [key], 10)) as nvarchar(max)) as path

Just curious to understand. What is this line saying

Comment: this is so row 9 doesn't come after of row 11, since they are sorted by ascii. it instead becomes 00000009 vs 000000011 which sorts correctly

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE to extract and parse the `content` attribute in each node:

```
with cte as(
    select  ID,type,text,content 
    from @table t cross apply OPENJSON(t.Description) with (
        type nvarchar(max),
        text nvarchar(max),
        content nvarchar(max) AS JSON)  
    as x
    union all
    select c.ID,u.type,u.text,u.content 
    from cte as c cross apply OPENJSON(c.content) with (
        type nvarchar(max),
        text nvarchar(max),
        content nvarchar(max) AS JSON) as u
)
select id,STRING_AGG(text,CHAR(13))  
from cte
where type='text'
group by ID
```

`content nvarchar(max) AS JSON` is needed to return the contets of the `content` attribute as a JSON string. Otherwise the column would be null.

Using this test JSON

```
declare @json nvarchar(max)=N'{
    "version": 1,
    "type": "doc",
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Please assign ticket to RCA team."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "RCA Team"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tClient code \u2013 5374 \u12345 Apple Financial"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tDividend Task ID \u2013 12345"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tPrevious MI IR Number - 12345"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Against the above task please can I have the following data:"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tHURN"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tPartyURN"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tEligible Share Balance"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tCash Currency Dividend Due"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tTax Deducted"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tholder name including any joint holders"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tCurrent full address"
                },
                {
                    "type": "hardBreak"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "-\tShare balance against task"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}';
```

And table

```
declare @table table(ID int primary key,Description nvarchar(max))
insert into @table (ID,Description) 
VALUES 
(1,@json),
(2,@json)
```

This produces :

````
id  Texts
1   - HURN - PartyURN - Eligible Share Balance - Cash Currency Dividend Due - Tax Deducted - holder name including any joint holders - Current full address - Share balance against task Against the above task please can I have the following data: - Client code – 5374 ሴ5 Apple Financial - Dividend Task ID – 12345 - Previous MI IR Number - 12345 RCA Team Please assign ticket to RCA team.
2   - HURN - PartyURN - Eligible Share Balance - Cash Currency Dividend Due - Tax Deducted - holder name including any joint holders - Current full address - Share balance against task Against the above task please can I have the following data: - Client code – 5374 ሴ5 Apple Financial - Dividend Task ID – 12345 - Previous MI IR Number - 12345 RCA Team Please assign ticket to RCA team.```
````

Comment: Looking at the sample data; although the op doesn't mention it, retaining the order appears to be relevant.

Comment: @MatBailie that's not the only problem. Ordering can be solved in SQL Server 2022 with a `WITHIN GROUP` order clause but older versions don't have this. The entire question isn't well though out, and looking at the unexpected output should help the OP understand why it's *not* a great idea to use SQL Server for this.

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I tried it and it is working. But as you can see the result from above JSON is in reverse. Text is aggregated from bottom of the JSON to top. How to show the aggregated text from top to bottom of this JSON?

Comment: I have edited the JSON code in the question for your reference. Kindly have a check on this and help me for aggregating in the same order please.